# Build docker image in gitlab ci with kaniko in local docker setup: suddenly cannot access container registry

Tags: docker-compose, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, kaniko, container-registry

## Setup

I'm running Gitlab (Omnibus) on a local server with docker compose (as described [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/docker.html#install-gitlab-using-docker-compose)).
Gitlab is globally reachable behind an Nginx reverse proxy (is a docker container as well: [nginxproxy/nginx-proxy](https://hub.docker.com/r/nginxproxy/nginx-proxy)) through a domain (for which a valid SSL certificate is provided).

I set up the Container Registry (CR) to store docker images. The CR is bind to a specific port of the host and is reachable from the internet as well. The CR listens to an internal port of the container. I mapped the container port to the host port as usual. Thus, the CR is not behind the Nginx proxy.
Therefore, I set the following in the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
...
services:
  gitlab:
    ...
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: 'global.gitlab.domain'
      VIRTUAL_PORT: '80'
      VIRTUAL_NETWORK: 'nginx_proxy_network'
      ...
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        ...
        registry_external_url 'https://global.gitlab.domain:registry_host_port'
        registry_nginx['listen_port'] = registry_container_port
        ...
    ...
      ports:
        - "registry_host_port:registry_container_port"
```

This setup works well for pushing and pulling images to/from the CR.

But now...

## The Error

I also set up a CI pipeline that builds docker images by utilizing kaniko (as described [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_kaniko.html)).
This worked fine for at least a year (I updated the gitlab and runner images once a week), and suddenly the jobs that build images and pushes them to the CR started failing with the following error:

```
$ /kaniko/executor --verbosity=debug --context "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}" --dockerfile "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/Dockerfile" --destination "${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:latest" --destination "${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:${CI_COMMIT_TAG}"
DEBU[0000] Copying file /builds/group/repo/Dockerfile to /kaniko/Dockerfile 
error checking push permissions -- make sure you entered the correct tag name, and that you are authenticated correctly, and try again: checking push permission for "global.gitlab.domain:registry_host_port/group/repo:latest": creating push check transport for global.gitlab.domain:registry_host_port failed: Get "global.gitlab.domain:registry_host_port/v2/": dial tcp 172.22.0.3:registry_host_port: connect: connection refused
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

172.22.0.3 is the IP of the `gitlab` service/container.

The above error shows, that kaniko tries to connect to the IP of the Gitlab container (172.22.0.3) and the `registry_host_port`. As I mentioned above, the container is listening to another port and this port (`registry_container_port`) is mapped to the host port. Thus, it's not surprisingly that this connection is refused.

## The Questions

First, let me explain the above "suddenly", when the jobs started failing ;)
I have tracked down the changes that happened to the server between the last successful (27.11.) job and the first erroneous job (04.12.).
The most suspicious change was that I migrated from `docker-compose` (v1) to `docker compose` (v2).

1. Why does kaniko try to access the IP of the Gitlab container directly instead of accessing the CR via the domain?
2. Could this be due to the migration from `docker-compose` (v1) to `docker-compose` (v2)?
3. Has the local Docker DNS behaviour changed recently?
4. Has anyone else experienced this error?

## Additional Setup Information

The runner itself is a container as well ([gitlab/gitlab-runner](https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-runner)) and resides on the same docker network as the Gitlab container (`gitlab_intern`).
This is his `config.toml`:

```
...
[[runners]]
  name = "docker-01"
  url = "http://gitlab"
  id = 0
  token = "XYZ"
  token_obtained_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "docker"
  clone_url = "http://gitlab"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "alpine:latest"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    network_mode = "gitlab_intern"
    shm_size = 0
```